# EF Core - ChangeTracker.DetectChanges get value from specific property

Tags: logging, entity-framework-core, audit-trail

I need to get the value of a property from a relationship in EF's ChangeTracker.

I have the class:

```
public class ClienteInfo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid IdTipoCliente { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    public bool Bloqueado { get; set; }

    public virtual TipoClienteInfo TipoCliente { get; set; }
}

public class TipoClienteInfo
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string Nome { get; set; }
     public bool Ativo { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<ClienteInfo> Clientes { get; set; }
}
```

To Audit Log, on property IdTipoCliente get property Nome of TipoClienteInfo

My ContextClass:

```
public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ClienteInfo> Cliente { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TipoClienteInfo> TipoCliente { get; set; }


    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
            {
                //GET HERE THE VALUE
            }
        }

        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
        return result;
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        RegisterMaps(modelBuilder);
    }

    public static void RegisterMaps(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ClienteMaps());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new TipoClienteMaps());
    }
}
```

I think use attribute, relfection, but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get property values from references (here: `ClienteInfo.TipoCliente`) by a query like this:

```cs
ChangeTracker.Entries<ClienteInfo>()
    .Select(e => e.Reference(c => c.TipoCliente)
                  .TargetEntry.CurrentValues["Nome"])
```

It's not clear from your question what exactly you want to do with these values but this should get you on the right track.

There are several ways to use this more dynamically and add variables/parameters, for example:

```cs
var referenceName = "TipoCliente";
var propertyName = "Nome";

var values = ChangeTracker.Entries<ClienteInfo>()
                  .Select(e => e.Reference(referenceName)
                                .TargetEntry.CurrentValues[propertyName])
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: I need get the value dynamic. this is a example, but its possible get any relationship ?

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question. Anyway, you can enter other property names or get the reference by name.

Comment: How can i get reference by name? could you code a example please?

Comment: Please see the addition. Maybe you'd want to return some more info from the `Select`, like `.Select(e => new { e.Entity, RefProperty = e.Reference ...})`.

Comment: `ChangeTracker.Entries<ClienteInfo>().(e => e.Reference(referenceName))` return de TargetEntry always return null, I'm using automapper to mapper DTO to CLASS, maybe this is a problem?

Comment: Not much I can say to that. It works in my own code. Make sure `referenceName` contains a reference property name that is spelled correctly.

Comment: Yes, exist but always return null

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question specifically focusing on getting the reference entry of a navigation property. In a new question you can create a [mcve] showing exactly what happens. Based on the information in this question I can't help you any further. This solution should work, is all I know.